# Analisando consumo de recurso por script

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, perl

Tenho um servidor com o S.O Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS, nessa maquina eu possuo o apache2 com o PHP5 e o PERL instalado, porém ela consume muito recurso de CPU, gostaria de saber se é algum script com problema mais para isso eu teria que rever um á um, mais a quantidade de arquivos é muito grande. Então gostaria de saber se tem alguma ferramenta que quando integrada ao apache me mostre quais scripts solicitados consomem mais recursos da maquina.

Comment: já ouviu falar no zend server tem tudo isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez duas ferramentas simples possam lhe dar uma direção melhor do que exatamente monitorar.

Eu utilizaria o *lsof* e o *strace*. Alguns exemplos:

1- Todos os arquivos sendo utilizados pelo usuário apache(arquivos podem ser qualquer coisa no linux, inclusive sockets de rede)

```
lsof -u apache
```

2- Todos os arquivos abertos por um processo (nome ou pid)

```
lsof -c httpd
lsof -p <PID>
```

3- Processos interagindo com um diretório ou arquivo (por exemplo, seu diretório de scripts, ou o próprio script)

```
lsof /var/www/cgi-bin
```

4 - Listar todas as chamadas de sistema de um processo

```
strace -p <PID>
```

Depois disso voce pode escrever monitores customizados para zabbix ou outra ferramenta de monitoramento para te reportar caso haja alguma situação suspeita, ou simplesmente para manter um histórico do que está acontecendo.

Outra alternativa é utilizar o mod_status do apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html

Comment: Obrigado a Ajuda, é quase isso que procuro. Porém preciso listar os recursos gastos por meus algoritmos PHP.

Comment: Então você vai ter que utilizar um _strace_ no apache ou de repente utilizar o mod_status ... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html

Comment: Vou fazer os testes e já lhe dou um retorno.

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, era o que eu precisava. Agora sei o arquivo requisitado juntamente com as informações dos mesmos, CPU, Transferência por conexão, dentre outras.

Comment: Pode editar sua resposta para eu marcar como resolvido?

Comment: de nada! Que bom que ajudou!

Answer (score 0):

Hiago,
da uma olhada na guia de configuração do apache no link

https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/multiform/index.cfm

e faz o download da guia, nele existe algumas opções de configurações que pode ser util nesse caso.

abs,

Comment: Obrigado @hulckb, mais você não conhece nada do tipo que eu perguntei? Ver o nome do arquivo que está sendo interpretado pelo php... Monitorar o uso de recursos por arquivos!? Mais obrigado a atenção.

Comment: Oi Hiago, existe varias ferramentas de monitoramento, ja utilizei ntop e zabbix muito boas .. com elas vc consegue monitorar os processos,etc ... abs

Comment: Assim, eu tenho conhecimento das mesmas, vou até te indicar uma bem legal que eu uso e a htop, porem o problema é esse tenho um processamento alto gostaria de saber onde tem gargalos para melhorar os processos mais nos processos aparecem somente o **apache -k start**