# Comparar performance de dois script PHP

Tags: php, linux, desempenho, script

Trabalhei num script **PHP**, mais tarde achei ele demasiado complexo e pesado e senti a necessidade de simplifica-lo.

- eliminei algumas funções desnecessarias;
- simplifiquei algumas partes do código repetidos em funções;
- optei por POO de modo a tornar o script mais compreensivel;
- ... etc;

Agora como poderia verificar se realmente ganhei em termo de **performance** ?
Como poderia comparar os dois escript nesse criterio :

- tempo de execucao ;
- consumo de recursos no servidor;
- ... etc;

Answer (score 3):

Tempo de execução sei responder, agora se o desempenho (performance) esta bom, levando em consideração o tempo de execução, acredito que depende mais do que seu algoritmo faz, fazer uma analise da complexidade e etc.

No inicio do algorítimo:

```
$time_start = microtime(true); // Inicializa a variável $time no inicio do seu script
.
.
{seu código aqui}
.
.
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo $time; // Te traz o tempo em milissegundos de execução do algorítimo
```

Em um script que pegava vários dados de outro servidor, me trazia o tempo de execução de 59s - 65s por exemplo.

Desempenho pode ser medido pela quantidade de `loops`, quantidade de funções recursivas, quantidade de funções parecidas que poderiam ser agrupadas, acredito que valha a pena dar uma lida em artigos sobre complexidade de algorítimos, que e uma matéria de engenharia/ciência da computacao bem extensa.

[Artigo sobre complexidade de algorítimos](https://www.ime.usp.br/~song/mac5710/slides/01complex.pdf)

Consumo de recurso, existem comandos internos em um servidor(linux, windows, entre outros) que podem ser usados para analisar a quantidade de recursos consumidas durante o tempo de execução de um script, infelizmente eu não tenho muita experiencia no assunto, mas existem [algumas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33992/analisando-consumo-de-recurso-por-script) aqui na rede que podem ajudar.